# AutoMapper: не работает динамический мапинг списков?

Tags: c#, automapper

Статический мапинг списков работает:

```
List<Models.Storages.Storage> result = null;
List<StorageDTO> list = storages_client.GetAll();
Mapper.CreateMap<StorageDTO, Models.Storages.Storage>();
result = Mapper.Map<List<StorageDTO>, List<Models.Storages.Storage>>(list);

// result.Count > 0 --> корректно работает
```

А вот динамический мапинг списков НЕ работает:

```
List<Models.Storages.Storage> result = null;
List<StorageDTO> list = storages_client.GetAll();
result = Mapper.DynamicMap<List<StorageDTO>, List<Models.Storages.Storage>>(list);

// result.Count == 0 --> работает НЕ правильно
```

Почему? В чем разница?

Answer (score 1):

Это исправлено в AutoMapper 4.0.0 и выше. Скорее всего [вот этим пуллреквестом](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/781).

Обновляйтесь.

Comment: Обновился был до 4.0.4 начались сыпаться exceptions вида: Trying map xxxDTO to Nullable type. WTF??? Вернулся снова на версию 3.3.0

Comment: @cpp_user делайте минимальный пример и постите на гитхаб автору automapper. пусть чинит. ну или сами почините, опен сорс жеж

Comment: Нету времени учитывая что версия 3.3.0 работает стабильно со статическим мапингом без exceptions.

Comment: @cpp_user тогда непонятно какого ответа вы ждете. это известный баг, затрекан и исправлен автором библиотеки. Это полный и единственный возможный ответ на ваш вопрос. То, что у вас "нету времени" хотя бы зарепортить проблему с апгрейдом - никак не влияет на полноту ответа. Ждете когда придет кто-то и скажет "да, в версии 3.3.0 есть меганастройка, включаешь ее и все работает"?

Comment: Баг поменял свое поведение (если раньше был просто пустой результат то теперь генерация какого то исключения внутри самой библиотеки) но в таком виде нельзя считать его как "исправленный".

Comment: @cpp_user у меня ваш код с тривиальными классами StorageDTO и Storage работает. И да, я проверил это до того, как запостил ответ. Если у вас не работает - приведите весь код. Вы напоролись на что-то специфическое именно для ваших классов.

Comment: @cpp_user хотя, если честно - можете не приводить. Минус на ответе и нежелание с вашей стороны хоть как-то локализовать  проблему - пусть кто-нибудь другой вас уговаривает.

Comment: Возможно проблема кроется в том что тип StorageDTO это сгенерированный тип из WCF Service Reference.